# NodeJS socket.io socket does not emit

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I'm working using socket.io on NodeJS to create bots for MooMoo.io. Everything seems to work fine except the bots will not accept a clan invitation.

Here is the part that is broken:

```
socket.emit("11", a, 1); // a = player ID
```

Here's my code:

```
const io = require("socket.io-client");
var socket = io.connect("http://52.39.43.139:" + (5006) + '', {
    reconnection: false,
    query: "man=1"
});
var n = 0;

function spawn(i) {
    n++;
    if (n >= 10) return null;
    socket = io.connect("http://52.39.43.139:" + (5000 + i % 11) + '', {
        reconnection: false,
        query: "man=1"
    });
    socket.once("connect", () => {
        socket.emit("1", {name: "ME"}); // spawn
        socket.emit("10", "ME"); // request to join clan
    });
}
socket.once("connect", () => {
    socket.emit("1", {
        name: "ME"
    }); // spawn
    socket.emit("8", "ME"); // create clan
    console.log("Clan created");
});

team = [];

var i = 0;
setInterval(() => spawn(i), 3000);
socket.on("an", (a, name) => { // player requests to join clan event
    socket.emit("11", a, 1); // accept invite
    console.log(`${name} successfully joined :)`);
    team.push(a);
    console.log(team);
});
socket.on("ad", (a) => { // player leaves clan event
    for (var c = team.length - 1; c >= 0; c--)
        if (team[c].sid == a) {
            team.splice(c, 1);
            console.log(team[c].name + ' has left');
        }
    console.log(team);
});
socket.on("11", () => { // respawn event
    console.log("I have died, respawning...")
    socket.emit("1", { // spawn event
        name: "ME"
    });
});
```

Comment: This is fairly confusing code.  Can you describe exactly what you are trying to accomplish and please make it very clear what code is client code and what code is server code.  Also, I see you doing `io.connect()` every 3 seconds (which does not seem like how you would normally use socket.io), but I don't see you disconnecting so it seems like you could just be accumulating connections.

Comment: @jfriend00 Hello. This is all client code here. I'm trying to create 5 connections to a moomoo.io server. Then I'm trying to get those bots to spawn and join a tribe.

Comment: Well, I don't know what "spawn and join a tribe" means so I guess I can't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the server limited one connection per port. Fixed by using different ports.

Answer (score 1):

According to the part you described as being broke you shouldn't pass extra variables like this:

```
socket.emit("11", a, 1); // a = player ID
```

But rather it should look like this;

```
socket.emit("11", {
   playerID:a,
   otherVariable:1
});
```

Which you can acess in your server code by using:

```
socket.on('11', function(data){
   console.log(data.playerID);
   console.log(data.otherVariable);
});
```

If you can provide more detail about other problems your having I can try to help you further, but you only highlighted that that emit didn't work and we don't have your backend code to reference here.

Another note, You shouldn't be passing anything but either a single variable (which the documentation still doesn't link and prefers passing via object) or an object. You also shouldn't be using `socket.once` in this context as it's not needed in my opinion

Comment: Hi, this isn't connecting to my server, so i don't know the backend either. Thank you for responding.